# ¿How to get the data of XML with php?

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, soap, foreach

I have the next problem, in my code I get a SOAP response in XML format so I want to loop it to get the info that the XML contain, the xml looks like this:

```
<?php
$xml_response = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REPORTES>
    DEMO
    <REPORTE TIPO="BASIC">
        <INVESTIGADO>SOMETHING</INVESTIGADO>
        <FECHA>SOMETHING</FECHA>
        <HORA>SOMETHING</HORA>
        <BASE>SOMETHING

            <PERIODO>SOMETHING</PERIODO>
            <JUICIO>SOMETHING</JUICIO>
            <GRADO>SOMETHING</GRADO>
        </BASE>
        <GRADO_MAXIMO>SOMETHING</GRADO_MAXIMO>
        <CASOS>
            <DEFINICION>SOMETHING</DEFINICION>
            <TIEMPO>SOMETHING</TIEMPO>
        </CASOS>
        <PDF_REPORT>SOMETHING</PDF_REPORT>
    </REPORTE>
    <REPORTE TIPO="DETAIL">
        <BASE>SOMETHING
            <INFORMACION>
                <JUZGADO>SOMETHING</JUZGADO>
                <JUZ_NUM>SOMETHING</JUZ_NUM>
                <SECRETARIA>SOMETHING</SECRETARIA>
                <FECHA_ACU>SOMETHING</FECHA_ACU>
                <NUM_BOL>SOMETHING</NUM_BOL>
                <FECHA_PUB>SOMETHING</FECHA_PUB>
                <RUBRO>SOMETHING</RUBRO>
            </INFORMACION>
        </BASE>
    </REPORTE>
</REPORTES>
EOF;
?>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the attribute "TIPO" because the child have a different structure, the problem is when the code prints the value only print the first

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
foreach ($xml->children()->attributes() as $key => $val) {
    echo "Key: " . $key . " value: " . $val . "<br>";
    var_dump($xml);
}
```

The output of the code

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["REPORTE"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (8)
 { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["TIPO"]=> string(5) "BASIC" } ["INVESTIGADO"]=> string(9) 

"SOMETHING" ["FECHA"]=> string(9) "SOMETHING" ["HORA"]=> string(9) "SOMETHING" ["BASE"]=> string(25) 

"SOMETHING " ["GRADO_MAXIMO"]=> string(9) "SOMETHING" ["CASOS"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (2) { 

["DEFINICION"]=> string(9) "SOMETHING" ["TIEMPO"]=> string(9) "SOMETHING" } ["PDF_REPORT"]=> 

string(9) "SOMETHING" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) 

{ ["@attributes"]=> array(1)
 { ["TIPO"]=> string(6) "DETAIL" } ["BASE"]=> string(16) "SOMETHING " } } }
Key: TIPO value: BASIC
```

I made the var_dumb to be sure that the all childs are present.
Finally the question is...
How can I make that the foreach get the attributes of child "REPORTES"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation doesn't really specify this, but you need to loop on the children method, or assign that value to a var before starting the loop. Basically do not chain your attributes method. Then it will work as expected.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
  foreach($child->attributes() as $key => $val) {
      echo "Key: " . $key . " value: " . $val . "<br>";
    }  
}
```